# POST Request redirects to GET in Nginx proxy and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, nginx, post, get

I have built a simple NodeJS app to demo REST API request handling. 
Then I used Nginx to proxy my Node app.
Then for testing, I used Postman to do a GET request which returns:

```
"message": "Handling GET request to /products"
```

which is good. But changing in Postman from GET to POST and then sending the request, it returns the same answer.

```
"message": "Handling GET request to /products"
```

If I use `curl` locally to make the requests (both GET and POST) I recieve good responses.

I use PM2 and running server.js

server.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');

app.use('/products', productRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

products.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handling GET request to /products'
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Handling POST request to /products'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

ngix site config

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /api/products {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/products;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

after I do the Postman POST request, here is the access.log from Nginx. The GET request was not called. It is just POST, though there is shown a GET request.

```
"POST /api/products HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
"GET /api/products HTTP/1.1" 200 47 "http://flipit.ro/api/products" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
```

The `"-"` shows me that POST request is not forwarded where it should.

I am new to Nginx/NodeJS so this may have a very simple and obvious solution, but don't judge me, as I am used to Apache/PHP. Also I am pretty bad at explaining things, but I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Why are there two locations? The second location seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: without the second one it says "Cannot GET /products" and without the first one it is the same thing.

Comment: You may want to add `rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /$1 break;` in your location. Then the /api will be similar to an alias. You can safely remove second location and access the service by localhost/api/products

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer. In postman I was calling

```
example.com/api/products
```

But as you see in Nginx config, the server listens on HTTPS. 
So it works with thihs HTTPS Postman call.

```
https://example.com/api/products
```

Comment: This is not an nginx cause. This happens because you set up nginx to send a redirect 301 http to https and your browser / postman does so, but does not preserve the method. See https://serverfault.com/questions/480052/why-is-nginx-changing-http-method-on-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an nginx issue and not a Node or Postman issue. Regardless of the HTTP method (`GET` or `POST`), a request to `/api/products` will result in a match on `location /api`.  I think you'll need to use the `=` modifier to do an exact match.

See [this Digital Ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks) on matching location blocks.

Hope that helps!